# Entity Framework - Foreign Key understanding

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, rest

Couldn't find a fully described tutorial on it, so i'm trying here.
I'm working in VS 2017, i got 3 tables.
The main one, ParkDB:

```
[Table("Parking")]
    public class ParkDB
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ParkID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ParkStartDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ParkEndDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("CityID")]
        public int ParkCityID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("StreetID")]
        public int ParkStreetID { get; set; }

    }
```

CitiesDB:

```
   [Table("Cities")]
    public class CitiesDB
    {
        [Key]
        public int CityID {  get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CityDesc {  get; set; }


    }
```

Streets Table:

```
  [Table("Streets")]
    public class StreetsDB
    {

        [Key]
        public int StreetID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("CityID")]
        public int CityID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string StreetDesc { get; set; }

    }
```

My goal is to be able to get an object with this fields:

[ParkID, ParkStartDate, ParkEndDate] - from ParkDb ,

[CityDesc] - from CitiesDB ,

[StreetDesc] - from StreetDB, all combined in one Parking object.

I was reading this article: [LINK](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

but i'm completely unsure what will work for me.
Also, any link for an article about how to make the actual call/query would be appreciated.. can't seem to find something helpful.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply navigation properties and the data annotations which you configured is invalid. I modified the entities like that;

```
[Table("Parking")]
public class ParkDB
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ParkID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ParkStartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ParkEndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ParkCityID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParkCityID")]
    public virtual CitiesDB City { get; set; }
}
[Table("Cities")]
public class CitiesDB
{
    [Key]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CityDesc { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StreetsDB> Streets { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ParkDB> Parks { get; set; }
}
[Table("Streets")]
public class StreetsDB
{
    [Key]
    public int StreetID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StreetDesc { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CityID")]
    public virtual CitiesDB City { get; set; }

}
```

I configured the `ForeignKey` attributes and remove the `ParkStreetID` from `ParkDB` entity because you should navigate it over `City` property. `CitiesDB` entity is central entity which is assosicated by other entities in this case.

Finally, I provide some navigation examples to provide better understanding;

```
ParkDBs.Select(x => x.City);//Get City by ParkDBs

CitiesDBs.SelectMany(x => x.Parks);//Get Parks by CitiesDB
CitiesDBs.SelectMany(x => x.Streets);//Get Streets by CitiesDB

StreetsDBs.Select(x => x.City);//Get City by StreetsDBs
StreetsDBs.SelectMany(x => x.City.Parks);//Get Parks of City which is assosicated with StreetsDB entity
```

Comment: Thanks, but im still not sure about 2 things.
First, if i try to populate it with some initial data with migrations, i tried this code for example:
  `Sql("INSERT INTO Cities (CityDesc) VALUES ('Tel Aviv')");
 Sql("INSERT INTO Parking (ParkStartDate, ParkEndDate) VALUES ('2018-01-15', '2018-01-15') WHERE CityID  = 1");
 Sql("INSERT INTO Cities (StreetDesc) VALUES ('Ibn Gavirol') WHERE CityID  = 1");`
It is just a guess, and it's not working

Comment: Second thing, how do i update my GET all parkings method for example?
This is how it is now:
`public IEnumerable<ParkDB> GetAllParkings()
        {
         
            return _context.Park.ToList();
        }`
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @Stormcloak, why you remove `ParkStreetID`? By logic (or by my understanding), there could be many Parkings on the one Street, and many Streets in one City. So, we need navigation property `Street` in `Parking` instead of navigation property`City`.

Comment: @AaYy, your inserts are not valid. 1st insert into `Cities` table, 2nd insert into `Streets` table, and 3rd into `Parking`. Your 3rd insert is not correct.

Comment: @Hemid, I removed it because ParkDB entity also has CityId. It should be either your scenario or mine.